# I want to remove 1/5 and show all legends in google pie chart

Tags: legend, pie-chart, google-visualization, legend-properties

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w4KY.png]

Here i have total 10 legends, but i want to show all 10 legends.

Comment: try moving the `legend.position` to the right, or top and increase `maxLines`...

Comment: thanks WhiteHat, but it doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

As **WhiteHat** mentions in his comment, you have to move the `legend.position` to the top and increase the `maxLines`.

But additionally, you have to add the `top` property to the `chartArea`, to get enough space at the top of the chart.

```
    {
      width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
      legend: { 
         position: 'top',         // <--- top position
         alignment: 'center', 
         maxLines: 5             // <--- increase of max lines
      },
      chartArea: {
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        top: "25%"           // <-- top space (you can use fix values as well. (e.x. 50))
      },
      sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
      pieHole: 0.4,
    }
```